# How to implement a MouseEnter Event on a Merged menustrip

Tags: c#

I'm new here and I hope to do well.

I'm working on a text editor (c#) in which I have a Father's Form and i can create several child's forms. When I open a child form his menuStrip merge whit his father's menustrip and I have all of the functionality of child's menuStrip on father's menuStrip (like some ToolStripMenuItems).
My problem is: I want to implement a MouseEnter event for those ToolStripMenuItems. This Event will change text on a toolStripStatusLabel(which is located only in Father's Form) writing on it the name of the ToolStripMenuItems who started the event. I can do it easy on all of ToolStripMenuItems of Father's menustrip but i have no idea of what can i do to started this event for all the ToolStripMenuItems of Child's menustrip. I want them to also change the ToolStripStatusLabel.

```
 public void ratonencima(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem aux = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = aux.Text;
    }
```

This is the method i call when I manage the MouseEnter event from a ToolStripMenuItem of Father's form. I want to add the event to the ToolStripMenuItem dinamically (at execution time) for not having troubles when i create a Child`s Form and his MenuStrip merge whit the fathers one.

What can i do?

Comment: Just stop thinking that merging is relevant.  Your child forms should fire an event when they get the MouseEnter event.  Your main form can subscribe it and update its status strip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found a solution for my problem.
I added dynamically the MouseEnter event to the ToolStripMenuIitems (and also i added a MouseLeave event to that ToolStripMenuItems to the text is changed to a blank string when it detects the event).

I added those methods on Father's form:

```
private void eventoaelementos()
 {
 foreach(ToolStripMenuItem t in this.menuStrip1.Items)
  {
    t.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(metodoMouseEnter);
    t.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(metodoMouseLeave);
    foreach(ToolStripItem t2 in t.DropDownItems)
    {
      if(t2 is ToolStripMenuItem)
      {
         //To discard the ToolStripSeparator's case in which I 
        //obtain an exception
          t2.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(metodoMouseEnter);
          t2.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(metodoMouseLeave);
       }
     }
   }
}

private void metodoMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
    }

    private void metodoMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ToolStripItem t = sender as ToolStripItem;
      if(t!=null)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = t.Text;
        }
    }
```

And i call to the eventoaelementos's method once i initialized the Father´s Form (On the constructor) and when I create a child's  Form (I have a "New" button on a MenuStrip on Father´s form and i added this method on the method I call when I Clicked on this button).

I hope you find this useful.

Thanks for your time.